# convert excel formulas to vba

Tags: excel, vba

i created this formulas for a specific work , i would like to convert them into vba , any help please?

formula 1:

> =MIN(INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q1_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q1_Ville2;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q1_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q1_Ville3;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q1_Ville2;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q1_Ville3;Villes1;0)))

formula 2:

> =MAX(INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q1_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q1_Ville2;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q1_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q1_Ville3;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q1_Ville2;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q1_Ville3;Villes1;0)))

formula 3:

> =MIN(INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville2;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville3;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville4;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville2;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville3;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville3;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville4;Villes1;0)))

formula 4:

> =MAX(INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville2;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville3;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville1;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville4;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville2;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville3;Villes1;0));INDEX(Distances;MATCH(Q2_Ville3;Villes2;0);MATCH(Q2_Ville4;Villes1;0)))

Comment: Do you wanna place this formula back to a cell? (if yes keep in mind it's restricted to 255 characters). Or do you wanna translate this formula to a VBA function?

Comment: i want to convert them in vba and clear the formulas from the cells

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, record your formula using Record_Macro, then you can see it visual basic editor in excel

Comment: and how can i make them all in one code and after it i click only on a button ? thanks

Comment: For example:Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
   'Formula1
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(R[-4]C[1],R[-4]C[2])"
    
   'Formula2
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(R[-4]C[2],R[-4]C[3])"
End Sub

Comment: i recorded the first formula, and i need to do the same and combine them in one vba

Sub minq1()
'
' minq1 Macro
' min q1
'

'
    Range("C26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=MIN(INDEX(Distances,MATCH(Q1_Ville1,Villes2,0),MATCH(Q1_Ville2,Villes1,0)),INDEX(Distances,MATCH(Q1_Ville1,Villes2,0),MATCH(Q1_Ville3,Villes1,0)),INDEX(Distances,MATCH(Q1_Ville2,Villes2,0),MATCH(Q1_Ville3,Villes1,0)))"
    Range("C27").Select
End Sub

Comment: Change Distances to "Distances"

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible translation to VBA for your first formula, the others you can do yourself now

```
Function MinRabiai(dist As Range, Q1V1 As Range, Q1V2 As Range, Q1V3 As Range, Villes1 As Range, Villes2 As Range) As Long
With Application.WorksheetFunction
MinRabiai = .Min(.Index(dist, .Match(Q1V1, Villes2, 0), .Match(Q1V2, Villes1, 0)), _
.Index(dist, .Match(Q1V1, Villes2, 0), .Match(Q1V3, Villes1, 0)), .Index(dist, _
.Match(Q1V2, Villes2, 0), .Match(Q1V3, Villes1, 0)))
End With
End Function

Sub tst()
MsgBox MinRabiai(Range("Distances"), Range("Q1_Ville1"), Range("Q1_Ville2"), Range("Q1_Ville3"), Range("Villes1"), Range("Villes2"))
End Sub
```